# Ebers–Moll model aF? Where does it come from?

Tags: transistors, bjt, datasheet, math, ebers-moll

I am just getting back into electronics after a long while. For the life of me I can't figure where the \$\alpha_F\$ variable in the Ebers–Moll model comes from when you are calculating \$I_C\$ or \$I_B\$ using the formulas given under the *Ebers–Moll* section on the [BJT Wiki Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor). My first instinct is that it is \$h_{fe}\$ , if I am to take the meaning of 'common base forward short-circuit current gain' literally, since \$h_{fe}\$ was the closest rating I could find in any datasheet.

So what I am asking is: Where do you get \$\alpha_F\$ when you are using the Ebers–Moll model of a BJT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

αF is not the Hfe of the transistor. Per the model, αF of the emitter current reaches the collector.

This means that αF of the diode current passing through the base-emitter junction contributes to the current flowing through the base-collector junction.

Typically, αF has a value of between 0.98 and 0.99. the forward beta (~hfe) is αF/(1-αF).

Comment: I did not think it was hfe! So what would I put into the equation then?

Comment: Use hfe on the datasheet and the relation in the answer to estimate αF: aF = hfe/(1+hfe).

Comment: Ok! That makes sense now. I missed that part at the end for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

It is **defined** as function of collector and emitter current. More specifically a ratio of the exponential functions which describe the current at the emitter and collector. You should find that the forward ratio is near unity.